What is missing when I get "Could not open conversion result ... for image" in dvipdfmx
I am working with a preprocessor that produces .tex files from .Rnw files in R.  It is designed to work with Japanese text, so I am using uplatex to process the .tex file into a .dvi, then dvipdfmx to produce the .pdf file.
I am getting errors that look like this:
dvipdfmx:warning: Could not open conversion result "/var/folders/0d/lm5nf_791193x0hxv5gvw5s40000gn/T/dvipdfm-x.f252e5fab932a739e4fa3d57b29ae18d" for image "./Japanese-001.eps". Why?
dvipdfmx:fatal: Image inclusion failed for "Japanese-001.eps" (page=1)

The file ./Japanese-001.eps is being referenced from the .tex file using \includegraphics{Japanese-001}, and it does exist in the current directory.
It looks to me as though dvipdfmx is trying to convert the .eps file to a format it can include, and is failing.  This could be because my system is missing some conversion tool, but I don't know what to look for.
Can anyone suggest what the problem is, and what I should do to fix it?

you need ghostscript installed to do eps to pdf conversion

@DavidCarlisle:  Thanks!  That was it.  If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

You need to install ghostscript to perform eps to pdf conversion
